# Group list of Timespans by values within x seconds range

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following values in a list:

```
[0] {-00:00:14.7100000} System.TimeSpan
[1] {-00:00:14.7000000} System.TimeSpan
[2] {-00:00:14.6900000} System.TimeSpan
[3] {-00:00:15.2000000} System.TimeSpan
[4] {-00:00:00.1300000} System.TimeSpan
[5] {-00:00:00.1200000} System.TimeSpan
[6] {-00:00:00.1000000} System.TimeSpan
[7] {-00:00:00.0900000} System.TimeSpan
```

Now I want to group these values in the following way.
Group 1:

```
[0] {-00:00:14.7100000} System.TimeSpan
[1] {-00:00:14.7000000} System.TimeSpan
[2] {-00:00:14.6900000} System.TimeSpan
[3] {-00:00:15.2000000} System.TimeSpan
```

and
Group 2:

```
[0] {-00:00:00.1300000} System.TimeSpan
[1] {-00:00:00.1200000} System.TimeSpan
[2] {-00:00:00.1000000} System.TimeSpan
[3] {-00:00:00.0900000} System.TimeSpan
```

So that I can build the avarage later on and get: **-14.826** and **-0.11**

I would take the first element of the list and look for any value that is within range x (3 Seconds should be fine in my case) of that value. Then I delete the match in the old list and add it into a new list. I figured I must use nested 'for loops' but I just don't know how in particular. How would you do this?

**EDIT:**
The values in the list are random. This means that defining groups beforehand won't do the job. I extended the example list.

**EDIT2:** The answer of Tim S. is what worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: `timeSpans.GroupBy(t => (int)t.TotalSeconds / 3)`

Comment: I think this only works if you want to have groups that range from 0 >= 3, 3 >= 6, 6 >= 9... But I want to have groups which depend on the actual values in the list.

Comment: RetroHelix, It is more than enough to this research-lacking, no-code question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple `while` loop and some LINQ. I also use [`yield return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) to make the code readable.

```
private static readonly TimeSpan GapSize = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TimeSpan>> GetGroups(IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timespans)
{
    var timespansList = timespans.ToList();
    while (timespansList.Count > 0)
    {
        TimeSpan min = timespansList.Min();
        var closeList = timespansList.Where(t => t - min <= GapSize).ToList();
        yield return closeList;
        foreach (var timeSpan in closeList)
        {
            timespansList.Remove(timeSpan);
        }
    }
}
```

You might also want to order your results (they retain original ordering here within each group; the groups come from lowest to highest) before returning. If performance is a concern, there are certainly more efficient ways to write the code, but this will get the job done!